# Convert std::string to complex<double> for a variety of formats

Tags: c++, string, complex-numbers

What is the best way to write a function `std::complex<double> str2complex(std::string str);` that converts a `std::string` containing a variety of formats to a `std::complex<double>`?

I am assuming that the string being given to this function contains only one complex number but it would be nice to also be able to do some error checking.

The formats that I would like it to work for are:

For the number real = `1.0`, imag = `0.0`:

```
(1.0)
```

For the number real = `1.0`, imag = `2.0`:

```
(1.0,2.0)
1.0+2.0i
1.0 + 2.0i
1.0+2.0*i
1.0 + 2.0*i
+1.0+2.0i
+1.0+2.0*i
+2.0*i+1.0
2.0*i+1.0
2.0i+1.0
```

For the first two, the standard `operator>>` should work but for the others I'm not sure what approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need a parser for this. For all that matters, you need to detect only '+' and 'i' in cases other than the first one.

My thought would be the following:

1. If '+' is the first symbol, start from second character
2. Read through string for the next '+'. Whatever read will be treated as one unit
3. If there's an 'i' in the string, this is the imag, parse the value to double imag. Otherwise, parse to double real. Be ware of '*'.
4. Repeat 2->3.